# How to get optimized java code from kotlin source file?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have converted below kotlin file from existing options

```
  @Entity
data class DatabaseVideo constructor(
        @PrimaryKey
        val url: String,
        val updated: String,
        val title: String,
        val description: String,
        val thumbnail: String)

/**
 * Map DatabaseVideos to domain entities
 */
fun List<DatabaseVideo>.asDomainModel(): List<DevByteVideo> {
    return map {
        DevByteVideo(
                url = it.url,
                title = it.title,
                description = it.description,
                updated = it.updated,
                thumbnail = it.thumbnail)
    }
}
```

The Java out put file is here as below

```
@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 18},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 2,
   d1 = {"\u0000\u0010\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010 \n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\u001a\u0016\u0010\u0000\u001a\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00020\u0001*\b\u0012\u0004\u0012\u00020\u00030\u0001¨\u0006\u0004"},
   d2 = {"asDomainModel", "", "Lcom/example/android/devbyteviewer/domain/DevByteVideo;", "Lcom/example/android/devbyteviewer/database/DatabaseVideo;", "app_debug"}
)
public final class DatabaseEntitiesKt {
   @NotNull
   public static final List asDomainModel(@NotNull List $this$asDomainModel) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$asDomainModel, "$this$asDomainModel");
      Iterable $this$map$iv = (Iterable)$this$asDomainModel;
      int $i$f$map = false;
      Collection destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList(CollectionsKt.collectionSizeOrDefault($this$map$iv, 10)));
      int $i$f$mapTo = false;
      Iterator var6 = $this$map$iv.iterator();

      while(var6.hasNext()) {
         Object item$iv$iv = var6.next();
         DatabaseVideo it = (DatabaseVideo)item$iv$iv;
         int var9 = false;
         String var10002 = it.getUrl();
         String var10003 = it.getTitle();
         String var10004 = it.getDescription();
         String var10005 = it.getUpdated();
         String var10 = it.getThumbnail();
         String var11 = var10005;
         String var12 = var10004;
         String var13 = var10003;
         String var14 = var10002;
         DevByteVideo var16 = new DevByteVideo(var13, var12, var14, var11, var10);
         destination$iv$iv.add(var16);
      }

      return (List)destination$iv$iv;
   }
}
// DatabaseVideo.java
package com.example.android.devbyteviewer.database;

import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

@Metadata(
   mv = {1, 1, 18},
   bv = {1, 0, 3},
   k = 1,
   d1 = {"\u0000\"\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0000\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0010\u000e\n\u0002\b\u0012\n\u0002\u0010\u000b\n\u0002\b\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\b\n\u0002\b\u0002\b\u0087\b\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B-\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\u0002\u0010\bJ\t\u0010\u000f\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0010\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0011\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0012\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0013\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0003J;\u0010\u0014\u001a\u00020\u00002\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u00032\b\b\u0002\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\u0003HÆ\u0001J\u0013\u0010\u0015\u001a\u00020\u00162\b\u0010\u0017\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0001HÖ\u0003J\t\u0010\u0018\u001a\u00020\u0019HÖ\u0001J\t\u0010\u001a\u001a\u00020\u0003HÖ\u0001R\u0011\u0010\u0006\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\t\u0010\nR\u0011\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000b\u0010\nR\u0011\u0010\u0005\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\f\u0010\nR\u0011\u0010\u0004\u001a\u00020\u0003¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\r\u0010\nR\u0016\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u00038\u0006X\u0087\u0004¢\u0006\b\n\u0000\u001a\u0004\b\u000e\u0010\n¨\u0006\u001b"},
   d2 = {"Lcom/example/android/devbyteviewer/database/DatabaseVideo;", "", "url", "", "updated", "title", "description", "thumbnail", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V", "getDescription", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "getThumbnail", "getTitle", "getUpdated", "getUrl", "component1", "component2", "component3", "component4", "component5", "copy", "equals", "", "other", "hashCode", "", "toString", "app_debug"}
)
@Entity
public final class DatabaseVideo {
   @PrimaryKey
   @NotNull
   private final String url;
   @NotNull
   private final String updated;
   @NotNull
   private final String title;
   @NotNull
   private final String description;
   @NotNull
   private final String thumbnail;

   @NotNull
   public final String getUrl() {
      return this.url;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getUpdated() {
      return this.updated;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getTitle() {
      return this.title;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getDescription() {
      return this.description;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String getThumbnail() {
      return this.thumbnail;
   }

   public DatabaseVideo(@NotNull String url, @NotNull String updated, @NotNull String title, @NotNull String description, @NotNull String thumbnail) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(url, "url");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(updated, "updated");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(title, "title");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(description, "description");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(thumbnail, "thumbnail");
      super();
      this.url = url;
      this.updated = updated;
      this.title = title;
      this.description = description;
      this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component1() {
      return this.url;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component2() {
      return this.updated;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component3() {
      return this.title;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component4() {
      return this.description;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final String component5() {
      return this.thumbnail;
   }

   @NotNull
   public final DatabaseVideo copy(@NotNull String url, @NotNull String updated, @NotNull String title, @NotNull String description, @NotNull String thumbnail) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(url, "url");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(updated, "updated");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(title, "title");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(description, "description");
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(thumbnail, "thumbnail");
      return new DatabaseVideo(url, updated, title, description, thumbnail);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static DatabaseVideo copy$default(DatabaseVideo var0, String var1, String var2, String var3, String var4, String var5, int var6, Object var7) {
      if ((var6 & 1) != 0) {
         var1 = var0.url;
      }

      if ((var6 & 2) != 0) {
         var2 = var0.updated;
      }

      if ((var6 & 4) != 0) {
         var3 = var0.title;
      }

      if ((var6 & 8) != 0) {
         var4 = var0.description;
      }

      if ((var6 & 16) != 0) {
         var5 = var0.thumbnail;
      }

      return var0.copy(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
   }

   @NotNull
   public String toString() {
      return "DatabaseVideo(url=" + this.url + ", updated=" + this.updated + ", title=" + this.title + ", description=" + this.description + ", thumbnail=" + this.thumbnail + ")";
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      String var10000 = this.url;
      int var1 = (var10000 != null ? var10000.hashCode() : 0) * 31;
      String var10001 = this.updated;
      var1 = (var1 + (var10001 != null ? var10001.hashCode() : 0)) * 31;
      var10001 = this.title;
      var1 = (var1 + (var10001 != null ? var10001.hashCode() : 0)) * 31;
      var10001 = this.description;
      var1 = (var1 + (var10001 != null ? var10001.hashCode() : 0)) * 31;
      var10001 = this.thumbnail;
      return var1 + (var10001 != null ? var10001.hashCode() : 0);
   }

   public boolean equals(@Nullable Object var1) {
      if (this != var1) {
         if (var1 instanceof DatabaseVideo) {
            DatabaseVideo var2 = (DatabaseVideo)var1;
            if (Intrinsics.areEqual(this.url, var2.url) && Intrinsics.areEqual(this.updated, var2.updated) && Intrinsics.areEqual(this.title, var2.title) && Intrinsics.areEqual(this.description, var2.description) && Intrinsics.areEqual(this.thumbnail, var2.thumbnail)) {
               return true;
            }
         }

         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
   }
}
```

It is seems to be buggy. very difficult to understand.is there any options to get pure java code ? please let me know if we can able to perform conversion other than android studio

Comment: I assume you are using the decompiler to see java generated code. My question is do you want to see the entire class or you want to analyze something in specific?

Comment: @PedroAGSantos yes i am using decompiler to see java code. i want to see exact same java class of that kotlin class .

Comment: Why do you assume this isn't the "exact same Java class"?  Why do you assume it's "buggy"?  It might be difficult to understand, but that's how Kotlin compiles its code.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sir , i got many extra code like "@Metadata"," Intrinsics.checkParameter" and etc this is making difficult to understand..

Answer (score 3):

You have to realise that kotlin runs on `JVM`,  hence it can do everything that `Java` can and nothing more. The extra features that `Kotlin` provides such as not null types etc are implemented using same byte code that java uses.

All the extra java code that you call "buggy", is there for some specific feature requirement of kotlin.

For example all the `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull` checks are there on variables that are declared non nullable, that is how kotlin makes sure that nulls are not introduced in such variables.

So the java output you see doesn't contain any extra code, its the actual java equivalent code of your kotlin class.